# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED socketIO

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, environment-variables

the error I receive is the following:

**GET http://process.env.vue_app_backend_api:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1592207631874 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

I am using a environement variable with vuecli3 for the ip address which is called VUE_APP_BACKEND_API.
I am also using Vue.js and VueSocketIO. 
I am not quite sure where this error stems from or which pieces of code are relevant.
Using this environment variable doing regular http-requests with axios works fine and using Vuesocketio i also was able to emit an event so I am confused where this error comes from.
However I  think I did not get this error when using a hardcoded IP.
This is the snippet of my connection to the websocket. If I should post some other code, please tell me!

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  // connection: SocketIO('http://localhost:5000'),
  connection: SocketIO(`http://${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API}:5000`),
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
  },
}));
```

Thank you in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

As you can realize, the environment variable is not being recognized because in the error, the library is trying to connect to an URL which corrsponds to your enironment variable, you should take a look to the use of environmental variables